# How to convert a database row into a JSON string of values only in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to provide a count of certain sizes of lockers.  My SQL statement is:

```
$sql = "SELECT Concat(`Height`, 'x', `Width`, 'x', `Depth`) as Locker, count(*) from lockers GROUP BY `Height`, `Width`, `Depth` ";
```

a var_dump in a loop of the rows gives me the following (many more rows are possible):

```
array(2) { ["Locker"]=> string(8) "15x30x45" ["count(*)"]=> int(6) }
array(2) { ["Locker"]=> string(8) "45x30x45" ["count(*)"]=> int(4) }
```

I want to obtain a JSON string that looks like this:

```
{
  "SizeList": {
    "15x30x45": 6
    "45x30x45": 4
  }
}
```

I have tried a lot of different methods (including converting it into an object, but I can't get the value of the size as an index.  For example, I get different variations of:

```
[0]=> string(31) "{"Locker":"15x30x45","count(*)":6}" 
[1]=> string(31) "{"Locker":"45x30x45","count(*)":4}"
```

Any help appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just manually create the object like this:

```
$sizeList = new stdClass();
foreach ($results as $row) {
    $sizeList->{$row['Locker']} = $row['count(*)'];
}

echo json_encode(array('SizeList' => $sizeList));
```